# how to customize article manager in Joomla administrator

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

i am not that much export in Joomla. and i stuck at one problem.

i want to add some custome fields in article manager page when we add / edit article from admin side. just like wordpress when i add some function in function.php page it reflacts on wp-admin side.

also i want that selection to be effect on front side.

can some one show me is there any way i can add a function in my theme which will show a custome selection fields on admin side and based on that front page changes.

i am using Joomla 3.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: What editor do you use on your website?

Comment: tinyMCE, just basic one which usally comes in joomla

Comment: Hi! Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at Stackexchange. You will have a better change to get an answer if you ask your question there. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a plugin to add this functionality. There is a recipe [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component). In the example they are using the #__user_profiles - table, which might be okay, but adding your own table might be more flexible.

This [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin) might also be a useful link.